# Is the film trophy bugged?

Tags: until-dawn

I'm on my final playthrough of Until Dawn and I am trying to get all of the collectibles. In the beginning of Chapter 2 where you play as Chris, there is a filmy trophy on the second floor which should grant The Twin's Clue #1, but nothing happened when I examined it. I tried putting it down and picking it up again a couple of times and still nothing. I came back as Sam (still Chapter 2), and I still don't get the clue after looking it over.

**Is this clue bugged? If so, is there any kind of work around for it?** I know you return to the house a few times in the story, so does anyone know if it will work in the other chapters? I'm going to take a guess that this issue was caused by patch 1.02 as I was able to get the clue my first time through (*my file was deleted, so I need to collect it again*) and have the trophy to show for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a little more testing, I am going to say that **the film trophy is indeed bugged** since it should be able to collected, was collectible in the past, and in this instance, was not collectible, especially since this behavior has been observed [else where](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/827528-until-dawn/72383881) (this [xkcd comic](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png) comes to mind).

As for a workaround, I have nothing concrete, but **I have been able to collect it** since posting this question. As a result, I will post what I did in hopes that it may help someone in the future.

1. After getting to Chapter 4, **I deleted my Until Dawn file** via the **System Storage Management menu**. This was primarily because I wanted to make a few different choices in the beginning.
2. I **rebuilt the PS4 database**. Doing some research yielded this as a potential solution to many problems, so I figured it could not hurt.
3. I made one different butterfly effect choice and that was to **let Matt see Mike and Emily**. I made some minor changes in my Analyst section choices as well.

I'm really hoping that it's either (1) or (2) that fixed my issue; I can't see how choices could bug the trophy since there shouldn't be any connection there, but it is listed *just in case*.

Comment: I missed that collectible on the first playthrough, but went back to that chapter after finishing the story and could collect it then. So even if you can't get it the first time, you might be able to go back for it by replaying that chapter (assuming you're not trying to do it all in a single playthrough).